# haddle click event for image that might have a corner ribbon covering part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have a div with an id of **items** holding a bunch of bootstrap cards each one has an  tag and some are followed by

```
<div class="ribbon"><span>Sale</span></div>
```

that puts a CSS ribbon across the top right corner of the image indicating that item is on sale.

I have a Jquery **on("click","img",function()**

```
$("#items").on("click", "img", function () {
    var path = $(this).attr('alt');
    if (path != "none") {
        $('#model-image-img').attr('src', path);
        $('#model-title').text($(this).attr('data-title'));
        $('#model-image').modal('show');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

that opens up a modal with a larger version of the image whenever it is clicked.

If the image happens to have a ribbon in the top right hand corner and the cursor is over the 100px x 100px box used to show the ribbon when the mouse is clicked nothing happens.

How do I deal with when the mouse is clicked over the ribbon so that it would open up the modal and show the larger image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a container let's say `<div class="offer">`. You put your image and the ribbon inside of that offer. Then you modify the handler

```
$("#items").on("click", "div.offer", function () {
    var path = $(this).find("img").attr('alt');
...
```

to make the click be triggered from the offer div.